# Excel VBA to clear selected rows

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I am trying to build a timer that fills rows using Application.Ontime but clears them if they are more than 30 minutes old. This is so I can run the timer indefinitely without accumulating more than 30 minutes of data and crashing my system. So far I can create a new data row every second successfully.

I have a time column on A and Column B is a tag with a 1 or 0 representing if the row is more than 30 mins old. Other Columns have data.
I would like my macro to look down from the first data row (row 10) and find the first row that is not blank (has not already been cleared) and has a 1 in Column B (is more than 30 minutes old) then clear the row. All other rows should be unaffected, and remain beneath the newly blanked space.

There should only ever be one row with a tag as this will run every second.

I would like to keep it clean and use rows.clear as selecting and deleting seems to slow the process down a lot..

Any help much appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: Sorry for lack of clarity, getting fuzzy.

Comment: Edit your question to include what you have tried (working or not). What does your narrative have to do with the title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Sub Clear()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change the name of your sheet

Lastrow = ws1.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

With ws1

i = 10
    Do
            If .Cells(i, "B") = 1 Then
                .Cells(i, "B").EntireRow.ClearContents
                '.Cells(i, "B").EntireRow.Delete
            End If

        i = i + 1
    Loop Until i > Lastrow
End With

End Sub
```

**EDIT#1**

Based on the comments below:

```
Sub Clear()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change the name of your sheet

Lastrow = ws1.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

With ws1

i = 1
TimeLimit = Time - TimeSerial(0, 30, 0)' Time limit NOW - 30 minutes
    Do

            If .Cells(i, "A") < TimeLimit Then ' If value in column A is less then the Timelimit then
                .Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.ClearContents
            End If

        i = i + 1
    Loop Until i > Lastrow
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean with "tagging"? My guess is that if ou are running this macro every second it might be possible that the macro did not finish to run entirely and you ask it to run again...

Comment: try to run the macro above once to see if it works as you expect. If yes, please accept the answer and post another question as it is another issu. But this time put your entire code and we will help you.

Comment: Hi yes sorry I am struggling here its very late! My timer code writes on the last empty row on the sheet. But I need the tag column (the 1 that tells the macro the age of the row)  to remain in place. it feels clumsy to me now - I am thinking it would be far more elegant if your more advanced macro took care of it by changing if B=1 to: if (lastrow, column A) > ( time limit as per cell at top of sheet).

Comment: It is not clear... First what is "time limit" a value? is it 1? And if you change to Cells(Lastorw, "A") it means that only the last row will be cleared. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes sorry I have marked it as answered thank you again!

Comment: My time limit is Now - 30 minutes. This is in a cell at the top of the sheet in decimal. Column A is the current time, also in decimal. So the idea was to have Column B say "1" if A>(Now-30). But I cant do that because the data rows from the timer start on the first empty row. So I either need to keep Column A unaffected by the timer, which is what i was inexpertly trying to do, or maybe even better, get the code you kindly wrote to directly compare Column A to the (time-30) cell and clear the row direct from that.

Comment: @DanS check my edit code. The code will erase the content of the entire row based on the column A (Column A has to be in Time format) if the time in column A is less then NOW - 30 minutes.

Comment: Hi Manu I had to wait for the weekend to continue but the edit works! Thanks again. My machine is struggling though, so I'm trying to change it so it starts at the first blank cell and loops until Time > Timelimit. I'm hoping this will reduce the strain on the machine.